# Sahi OS: Install certificate option is not showing on IE9 (Certificate error)

Tags: sahi

Whenever i go to the browser through sahi os and i run the script then in between certificate error comes and when I hit continue then only am able to proceed. Can you please advise me how to get rid of this "certificate error" issue?

I am testing in IE9, with Windows 7 OS.

Answer (score 0):

Usually, adding the certificat to your trusted certificates for this specific browser solves the issue. Check your SSLManager for the cert in question. And then google for something like "adding certificate exception [browser]"

Regards
Wormi